# Weblogic user automatically getting deleted during weblogic server start up

Tags: weblogic-10.x, osb

I created a user in weblogic by following the below steps:
1. clicked on security realams present on left side panel.
2. clicked on myrealam
3. clicked on user and groups
4. clicked on new
5. Provided user name and password

The user created successfully. However when I am starting the server by deleting the log,cache, tmp and data folder. The created user is getting deleted automatically.

From my first level analysis I found its due to the deletion of data folder.
I want to create a permanent user for security validation.

Can anyone Please help me to create a permanent user.

Regards
Asutosh Kar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to solve my above issues.
There are 2 ways to solve the above issue:
1. Export the LDAP files from the security realms to a directory present in the server and delete the data directory and restart the server. After restart of the server again import the LDAP files.
2. Modify the DefaultAuthenticatorInit.ldift present under the domain security directory to add the user and group details. After that delete the data directory and restart the server.

Regards
Asutosh Kar

Answer (score 0):

I tried following and it works

1. Login to weblogic console.
2. Navigate to domain.
3. Under domain , security tab > Embedded LDAP
4. Select Master First and then restart servers.

The users created after restart will remain in the system